# how JVM secures file access.?

Tags: java, security, jvm

How does JVM secures file access from the application.

Suppose we downloaded an applet and we are running it from user with admin privilege.
And suppose it was written in such a way that it will delete some important files from your system  Will JVM prevent these operations by default?

Thanks

Comment: File access control belongs to OS. How could the JVM know about "important" files?

Comment: Yes you are correct OS is having file access control. But is there some security measure taken by JVM that will check these kind of malicious codes? I came to know that JVM is following sandbox security.But i don't know much about it.

Comment: In applets, follow @Peter Lawrey advice, as jre's securitymanager controls file input/output operations (among many other things). But JVM does not know, just prevents by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets are run with a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html). This controls all the security sensitive operations.

Comment: Thank you :) so after checking the link you have given, my understanding is as follows: we have to get permission from SecurityManager before doing a file operation and if it allows we can do it. Am i correct?

Comment: If one is set. When you run `java` from the command line, there is no SecurityManager by default. For applets there is usually a SecurityManager which prevents some operations, but can prompt the user as to whether to allow others.

Comment: So its up to the developer to do the checking. So if some bad person decided not to do so, he can have full access to the system files?

Comment: Yes. If you are concern a Java program hasn't defined a SecurityManager you can specify it on the command line to ensure there is one.